# Gitlab CI - Why job`s `image` settings affect global `before_script` and `image`?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Exist pipeline configured according [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor)

```js
image: docker:stable

variables:
   DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
   DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker version

stages:
  - test

test:lint:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
  cache:
    paths:
    - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm i -g yarn
    - yarn
    - yarn lint
```

Pipeline output collapsing as expect here

```
$ npm i -g yarn
/bin/sh: eval: line 85: npm: not found
```

but I get successfully docker info from `before_script` section, because I have `docker` services created globally

Then I want edit my failed job and base it on image with `node` where I can use `npm` command.

New pipeline

```js
image: docker:stable

variables:
   DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
   DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker version

stages:
  - test

test:lint:
  image: node:10.13-alpine
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
  cache:
    paths:
    - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm i -g yarn
    - yarn
    - yarn lint
```

and get error for `before_script`

```
/bin/sh: eval: line 83: docker: not found
$ docker version
```

why do i get this behavior? In [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-from-gitlab-ciyml) I cannot find info about this behaviour

Comment: In your `test:lint` job, you use `tags` which is used to select specific Runners from the list of all Runners. I don't understand why are you using this when you're already using `image` and `services` globally ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster I use my private runners depend on this tag and for that job I want use another image with npm utils. I'm confused why specific job affects before script

Comment: Which executor do you use ? Could you provide the job execution logs (something like `Using ... executor with image`) ?